# How can I event to another function from addEventListener without anonymous function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to use `addEventListener` to get something from 'event', but after used I have to use `removeEventListener` to remove event listener. How can I do for this situation?

Example:

```
    var elem = document.createElement('div');

    // I need argument of *event*
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(*event*){
         console.log(*event*)
    });

    // after used, I have to remove it, but only named function can be removed
    elem.removeEventListener('click', function(event){
    
    });
    // this way can be actually removed, but I need *event*
    elem.removeEventListener('click', namedFunc);
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Ok, I have resolved this issue...

Comment: You might want to [post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the way you did it, btw

```
function once(el, ev, cb){
    el.addEventListener(ev, function f(event){
        cb.call(event, event);
        el.removeEventListener(ev, f);
    }, false);
}
```